# Sepparating wix image database through pages

Tags: javascript, velo

Good morning,
I am learning how to work on wix for a school project and i have a database with 148 rows.

The database contains name(key), image, nickname and description.
The database is being all loaded onto a single page through a repeater but 148 images in a single page makes it to slow to open.

How do i make to separate it just like when you search on google, you have page 1 2 3 4....
This has to work with a search bar.

The repeater alredy is connected to the database and the search bar code is the following:

```
import wixData from "wix-data";

let lastFilterTitle;
let debounceTimer;
export function input1_keyPress(event, $w) {
    if (debounceTimer) {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
        debounceTimer = undefined;
    }
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        filter($w('#input1').value, lastFilterTitle);
    }, 200);
}

function filter(title) {
    if (lastFilterTitle !== title) {
        let newFilter = wixData.filter();
        if (title)
            newFilter = newFilter.contains('title', title);
        $w('#dataset1').setFilter(newFilter);
        lastFilterTitle = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a dataset attached to the repeater, the dataset is already paginated as long as you limit the page size in the dataset settings. If you attach a pagination bar (Ad > Interactive > Pagination Bar), and bind it to your same dataset, it will automatically create pagination for your dataset.

When using search, you should use the [setFilter function](https://www.wix.com/corvid/new-reference/wix-dataset/dataset/setfilter) on the dataset, not wixData, to make sure you don't lose the paging.